# Grafana not reading results properly

Tags: parsing, grafana, zabbix

My problem is the following

I have this text

> ID:
>
> Origem: 4
>
> Mensagem: Parametro invalido: CHASSI_INVALIDO: chassi
>
> Gateway: 2
>
> Versao: v20170130
>
> Layout: BASERNS2
>
> Data: 2017-04-10 10:00:04.592

And grafana (doesnt matter the panel) reads like this

> ID: Origem: 4 Mensagem: Parametro invalido: CHASSI_INVALIDO: chassi
>   Gateway: 2 Versao: v20170130 Layout: BASERNS2 Data: 2017-04-10
>   10:00:04.592

How can I get for Grafana to show the result properly, with the 'new line'?
Is that even possible?

Thanks

Comment: How is Zabbix related (a tag is added) ?

Comment: This also seems to be offtopic here, and there is a duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325448/grafana-not-reading-results-properly .

Comment: @Richlv no tags
Why offtopic? How can I correct? and the link you sent is the same of this page ._.

Comment: Oops, copypaste issue - duplicate at http://serverfault.com/questions/843676/grafana-not-reading-results-properly .

Comment: It's not Zabbix issue. It's only Grafana problem, so zabbix tag is not relevant here.